# How do you invoke another app from a child browser

Tags: android, browser

We have an app with an advertising SDK. 
The click through url has been configured to open in a child browser. The issue arises if the click through url is a redirection to deeplink into another installed application or a redirection to the Playstore. How should we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("foo://")) {
            Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(launchIntent);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, this would invoke only a specific app right. What if i needed to invoke multiple apps depending on the advertiser.